# Reverse proxy from apache to tomcat (for https to http)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I am trying to front my `tomcat` installation with `Apache 2` webserver. The idea is to let `apache` handle the `SSL/https` part and then forward the normal request to the tomcat on same machine running on port **8080**.

As mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension), I am using the following configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ServerName my-server-name.com
</VirtualHost>

Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-server-name.com/cert-file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-server-name.com/key-file
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-server-name.com/chain-file

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

The above configuration is resulting in :

1. Visiting `http://my-server-name.com` is opening the `tomcat` landing page
2. Visiting `https://my-server-name.com` is opening the `apache` landing page

But what I expect is to always redirect to `https://my-server-name.com` which should open the `tomcat` landing page (which will evantually be replaced by my application deployed on the ROOT)

Can someone please guide me or any pointer to a step by step guide to front `tomcat` with `apache` for `https` to `http` handling

Comment: Aren't there any other VirtualHosts listening on port 443?

Comment: @Lacek: no, just the ones I mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

The first vhost isn't needed as it seems and the `NameVirtualHost` directive can also be dropped, resulting in:

```
Listen 80    
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=Permanent,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-server-name.com/cert-file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-server-name.com/key-file
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my-server-name.com/chain-file

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This didn't work and the result is :

  1. `http://my-server-name.com` mapped to `apache webserver` and not the `tomcat`

  2. `https://my-server-name.com` mapped to `apache webserver` and not the `tomcat`

Comment: But the Apache doesn't listen on 8080 and Tomcat does? - edited my answer to force HTTPS on HTTP-requests

Comment: And you should have Apache modules `proxy`, `proxy_http` and `rewrite` activated...

Comment: I've the modeules activated. Also, the above mentioned updated changes just made `http` to be `https`; but the request is still not being transferred to tomcat. I can see the `apache2` welcome page and not `tomcat`

Comment: But the Apache doesn't listen on 8080 and Tomcat does? It seems like Apache still 'wins' the fight for port 8080...Myb turn up the errorlog to see more of what is happening `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace2` should show you more than enough info, provide the relevant (if you can distinguish it^^) as an update of your post, if necessary clean up IPs and servernames...

Comment: Yup, `apache` on port `80` and `tomcat` on `8080` is the setup. I'll try to capture the logs and will see if that helps. Will paste here if something comes up. Thanks

Comment: @HelloFishy your http vhost redirect anything, try to check using curl -I http://yourwebserver.comt/index.php -H 'Host: google.it', So I think that I can use your site to redirect users everywhere, without using servername, your apache will match every host request in the default vhost.

Answer (score 0):

On my server I have this configuration for your question:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myserver.error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myserver.log combined

#settings for AJP to tomcat
   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myserver.error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myserver.log combined

   <Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/privkey.pem
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/cert.pem

#settings for AJP to tomcat
   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

</VirtualHost>
```

I forward via AJP 8009, this is usually activated in tomcat. In apache the *mod_proxy_ajp* has to be enabled. But the configuration would work with *http* too.
Difference from my config to your's:
I don't have

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
```

and

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

Comment: This again didn't work and resulted in the similar behavior as earlier

Comment: what's logged, if you add the ErrorLog and CustomLog like in my example?
On what OS are you running that? <br>
Today I tested a similar installation on Debian, I had to disable the default site of apache `a2dissite 000-default`